# How can I clean up this REGEX pattern?

Tags: .net, regex

I am not great at regex.  A customer of mine is using this pattern

```
\b^[0-8]\d{7}\b|customer[]{0,1}id|cifid|customer_id|cif_id|^cif|gcif|customernumber|customer_no|cust_id|custid|customerid|[_]+cif|cust_nb
```

When I run it through regex 101.  This portion of the pattern isn't hit:

```
[]{0,1}id|cifid|customer_id|cif_id|^cif|gcif|customernumber|customer_no|cust_id|custid|customerid|[_]
```

so cif_id doesn't match this pattern.

The software is using the .NET regex library. Can anyone help me clean this up?

I appreciate any help in explaining and cleaning up this pattern.

Comment: You can't just 'clean up' a regex without knowing both what it should match and what it shouldn't match. So you must provide examples of both.

Comment: I'm guessing here: you want to match literally `[]` characters. If that's the case, you should escape those `\[\]`.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Bak

that helped a lot.

Can you help me understand what this portion is doing? \b^[0-8]\d{7}\b|customer[]{0,1}id